# Bind mount but exclude a subdirectory

Tags: mount, bind-mount

I'm using a chrooted Debian inside my router's base Linux OS. I want to move bind as many directories from the rootfs in the chroot as possible. All good so far. however, when it comes to the mnt directory I cannot bind this because the Debian chroot is on a USB inside this directory so it would create an endless loop of [Base system:**/tmp/mnt/opt/debian**][Debian chroot:**/mnt/opt/debian**]...

This would be rather easy to solve if I could bind the mnt directory and simply exclude the ./opt subdirectory, in something similar to:

```
mount -o dev,exec,defaults,bind /tmp/mnt --exclude-subdir /opt /opt/debian/mnt
```

Any ideas on how I could do this?

Comment: Mount usb to somewhere else.

Comment: @IporSircer I know I could do that because of some more complicated reasons involving how the built in ftp server on the router only shares directories inside /tmp/mnt I need to do it this way.